# how to exclude smartphones in Syamntec to connect only for releasing build and not as a USB storage

Tags: sentinel, symantec, android-device-controls

I am using Symantec Cloud Endpoint 14, we basically blocked all the USB access via device control, and we excluded a couple of USB Storage (pendrive) devices for internal purpose. Now we need to allow android and iOS smartphone devices to a couple of Mobile APP developers.

My requirement is: How do I exclude the SmartPhones in Symantec to only release the build and test the APPs from their systems through AndroidStudio/xCode and Not as a USB MASS Storage ?
so this way we can allow the developers to work without issues and also the they will not be able to transfer any data from systems to the SmartPhones.

Let me know your inputs.

Thanks

I have tried excluding MIDI Device ID of the SmartPhone and Tested through the AndroidStudio and xCode but its not working.

Comment: "also the they will not be able to transfer any data from systems to the SmartPhones", I don't think it's possible for Android, pushing the APK and running it with debug permission inherently have more than enough privilege to write arbitrary data to the smartphone. Now that I think about it, this is similar to iOS, nothing stops them to package arbitrary file as resource and then have the app write that resource into a file

Comment: @Martheen, I figured out I am able to do this restrictions with the Symantec Endpoint device control, its a bit tricky but we can do. Thanks